# How to Add New Fields in Dokan Product Form to Specify New and Used product, and Can Filter the Products by Used and New One

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, dokan

I'm working on a WordPress/Dokan plugin. I am looking for a way to add a new field by two selectable options, New and Used product. Also, The visitors can filter the products in the shop page or search results page by New and Used products.  I would really appreciate it if someone can help me?

I tried the following code. But when I add it to the child-theme, it disrupts the website function.

```
// ****adding extra field in single product page START****

// Adding extra field on New product popup/without popup form
add_action( 'dokan_new_product_after_product_tags','new_product_field',10 );

function new_product_field(){ ?>

     <div class="dokan-form-group">
              <label class="dokan-control-label" for=""><?php _e( 'Item condition', 'dokan' ); ?></label>
                <div class="dokan-form-group">
                    <select name="new_field" class="dokan-form-control">
                        <option value=""><?php _e( '', 'dokan' ) ?></option>
                        <option value="new"><?php _e( 'New', 'dokan' ) ?></option>
                        <option value="used"><?php _e( 'Used', 'dokan' ) ?></option>
                    </select>
                 </div>
        </div>

   <?php
}

/*
* Saving product field data for edit and update
*/

 add_action( 'dokan_new_product_added','save_add_product_meta', 10, 2 );
 add_action( 'dokan_product_updated', 'save_add_product_meta', 10, 2 );

function save_add_product_meta($product_id, $postdata){

    if ( ! dokan_is_user_seller( get_current_user_id() ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // if ( ! empty( $postdata['new_field'] ) ) {
        //     update_post_meta( $product_id, 'new_field', $postdata['new_field'] );
        // }
        update_post_meta( $product_id, 'new_field', $postdata['new_field'] );
}

/*
* Showing field data on product edit page
*/

add_action('dokan_product_edit_after_product_tags','show_on_edit_page',99,2);

function show_on_edit_page($post, $post_id){
$new_field         = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'new_field', true );
?>
   <div class="dokan-form-group">
       
        <label class="dokan-control-label" for=""><?php _e( 'Item condition', 'dokan' ); ?></label>
              <select name="new_field" class="dokan-form-control">
                    <option value="new" <?php echo ( "new_field" == 'new' ) ? 'selected' : 'Used' ?>><?php _e( 'New', 'dokan' ) ?></option>
                    <option value="used" <?php echo ( "new_field" == 'used' ) ? 'selected' : 'New' ?>><?php _e( 'Used', 'dokan' ) ?></option>
                </select>

     </div> <?php
    }

// showing on single product page
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','show_product_code',13);

function show_product_code(){
      global $product;

        if ( empty( $product ) ) {
            return;
        }
 $new_field = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'new_field', true );
 if (empty($new_field)) exit;

        if ( ! empty( $new_field ) ) {
            ?>

<span><?php echo esc_attr__( 'Item condition:', 'dokan' ); ?> <strong><?php echo esc_attr(    $new_field ); ?></strong></span>
            <?php
        }
}
// ****adding extra field in single product page END****
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated code you should try

```
<?php 
// ****adding extra field in single product page START****

// Adding extra field on New product popup/without popup form
add_action('dokan_new_product_after_product_tags', 'new_product_field', 10);

function new_product_field() {
    // Security: Nonce field
    wp_nonce_field('new_product_field_nonce', 'new_product_field_nonce_name');
    ?>
    <div class="dokan-form-group">
        <label class="dokan-control-label" for="new_field"><?php _e('Item condition', 'dokan'); ?></label>
        <select name="new_field" class="dokan-form-control">
            <option value=""><?php _e('Select condition', 'dokan'); ?></option>
            <option value="new"><?php _e('New', 'dokan'); ?></option>
            <option value="used"><?php _e('Used', 'dokan'); ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <?php
}

/*
* Saving product field data for edit and update
*/

add_action('dokan_new_product_added', 'save_add_product_meta', 10, 2);
add_action('dokan_product_updated', 'save_add_product_meta', 10, 2);

function save_add_product_meta($product_id, $postdata) {
    if (!isset($_POST['new_product_field_nonce_name']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['new_product_field_nonce_name'], 'new_product_field_nonce')) {
        return;
    }

    if (isset($postdata['new_field']) && !empty($postdata['new_field'])) {
        update_post_meta($product_id, 'new_field', sanitize_text_field($postdata['new_field']));
    }
}


/*
* Showing field data on product edit page
*/

add_action('dokan_product_edit_after_product_tags', 'show_on_edit_page', 99, 2);

function show_on_edit_page($post, $post_id) {
    $new_field = get_post_meta($post_id, 'new_field', true);
    ?>
    <div class="dokan-form-group">
        <label class="dokan-control-label" for="new_field"><?php _e('Item condition', 'dokan'); ?></label>
        <select name="new_field" class="dokan-form-control">
            <option value="new" <?php selected($new_field, 'new'); ?>><?php _e('New', 'dokan'); ?></option>
            <option value="used" <?php selected($new_field, 'used'); ?>><?php _e('Used', 'dokan'); ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// showing on single product page
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_product_code', 13);

function show_product_code() {
    global $product;

    $new_field = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), 'new_field', true);
    if (!empty($new_field)) {
        echo '<span>' . esc_html__('Item condition:', 'dokan') . ' <strong>' . esc_html($new_field) . '</strong></span>';
    }
}

// ****adding extra field in single product page END****
```

Comment: Thank you very Much Jenny. I tested your code. But the result is not showing up in the Single Product Page. Also on the edit product page, after selecting and saving the second option (used) and refreshing the page,  the field stay on the new. Basically, the field should indicate the saved option.